# Online tool to validate javascript file

Tags: javascript

Is their any online tool / web site to check / validate javascript syntax , present in javascript file.

As I am having issue with IE 7 while executive javascript , So I need to validate my Javascript file.

Comment: Please don't "tag-spam" your questions with a bunch of tags that have nothing to do with the content of your question.  Edited.

Answer (score 1):

http://jslint.com/

You may have to tweak the options a bit otherwise you write VERY strict Crockford approved code which might otherwise have been desirable if you know what you are doing.